# Horizontally aligning divs inside a column

Tags: html, css, alignment

I think I'm missing something obvious.  Under my slider, I have 3 boxes that contain 3 elements per box.

1. Text
2. Jpg
3. embedded video

The text and the jpg should be on the same line with the video lined up directly underneath.

All 3 boxes should be evenly spaced horizontally across the column.

Here's my current output:

http://test.completesources.com/fitnesspro/

Here's my code:

http://jsbin.com/qucewa/edit?html,css,output

I'm just learning webdev and trying to duplicate a site as practice.  I think if I can get these boxes to work, I'll have the rest of the site.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try by adding css

```
    .box {
     background: blue;
     margin: 5px;
     /* width: 15%; */
     display: inline-block;
     overflow: hidden;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, Rahul.  I did that and it lined everything up correctly, but the videos were incorrectly sized.  Changed iframe width to 100% and it did the final trick.  

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try incorporating `table` elements like this:

```html
<div class="box"> 
  <div class="break"></div><table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td><div class="box_text">Training Tips</div></td>
        <td><img class="barbell" src="images\barbell.jpg"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
     <td colspan="2"> <iframe width="247" height="247" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/u_iG_DWLdN8?showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="" style="width: 100%"></iframe></td>
      </tr>
 </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.box {
  background: blue;
  margin: 5%;
  width: auto;
  display: block;
  float: left;
}

.box_text {
  color: #F3D000;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 1%;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

And give your iframe

```
iframe {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To make the text and image on the same line;
use vertical-align property. read more about it at http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_vertical-align.asp

CSS:

```
.box_text {
color:#F3D000;
font-weight:bold;
font-size:1.5em;
vertical-align: middle;
}
```

HTML:

```
    <div class="box_text">
        Training Tips<img class="barbell" src="images\barbell.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="break"></div>
```

and to make the boxes spaced horizontally across the column, use float:left.

```
.box {
background:blue;
margin:5%;  
width:21.333%;
float:left;
}
```

The total margin and width of the horizontal div must be equal to 100 or 99.999% in order to make the boxes evenly spaced. Total space = box1 + box2 + box3 =(5%+21.333%+5%) + (5%+21.333%+5%) + (5%+21.333%+5%) = 99.999%. If you decrease the margin, make sure you increase the width and then total it up approximately to 100%.

By the way, I just saw you set your iframe width to 20%, when the boxed horizontally spaced together later on, the 20% width of iframe will be calculate from the width of the .box. Increase the size to 100% if you want the iframe width to be equally same size with the box size. Example:

```
iframe {
  //display:inline-block;
  width:100%;
}
```

or, if you want the iframe to certain width, here is the example:

```
iframe {
  //display:inline-block;
   margin-right: 10%;
   margin-left : 10%;
   width:80%;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed answer.  I knew there was some math involved, but not sure where I was supposed to be headed with it.  That helps a lot!